# using a selection box to change font with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 text input boxes that i want to allow a user to change the font of, but im not sure how to do this.

This is the code for my preview boxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $(".line1").keyup(function()
    {
    var word=$(this).val();
    $(".line_preview1").html(word);
    return false;
    });
    $(".line2").keyup(function()
    {
    var word=$(this).val();
    $(".line_preview2").html(word);
    return false;
    });
    $(".line3").keyup(function()
    {
    var word=$(this).val();
    $(".line_preview3").html(word);
    return false;
    });
});
</script>


<span class="line_preview1"></span>
<span class="line_preview2"></span>
<span class="line_preview3"></span>
<input type="text" name="line1" class="line1" />
<input type="text" name="line2" class="line2" />
<input type="text" name="line3" class="line3" />
```

If i could choose the font for each line that would be great

**edit for context**

i would like to have;

```
<select name=font>
<option>Arial</option>
<option>Verdana</option>
<option>Times New Fubar</option>
</select>
```

when a new option is chosen, it would update the css of the specific preview element

Comment: What do you mean by `choose the font`? Should the user be able to enter a font name somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the CSS attributes with [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$("a#change_font").click(function(){
  $("div#fontchange").css('font-family', 'Courier, mono');
});

<a href="#" id="change_font">Change it!</a>
<div id="fontchange">Hello World!</div>
```

There's an article here which describes how to use it with select-values: [Getting Select List Values](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-select-list-values).